# CAShapeLayers not drawing in custom subclass (UIControl)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm having a strange problem when trying to draw a couple of CAShapeLayer in a custom UIControl subclass. I'm sure it's something obvious, but after 24h, I can't make it work.

I'm doing it like this:

```
// .h
@interface IntercomButton : UIControl

@end

// .m
@interface IntercomButton()
@property (nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *outerCircle, *innerCircle;
@end

@implementation IntercomButton

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _innerCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        _outerCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        _innerCircle.frame = frame;
        _outerCircle.frame = frame;

        [self.layer addSublayer:_innerCircle];
        [self.layer addSublayer:_outerCircle];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    _innerCircle.frame = self.frame;
    _innerCircle.strokeColor = NULL;
    _innerCircle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.377 green:0.664 blue:0.894 alpha:1.000].CGColor;
    _innerCircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(self.frame, 12, 12)].CGPath;
    //_innerCircle.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    //_innerCircle.shouldRasterize = YES;
    //[self.layer addSublayer:_innerCircle];

    _outerCircle.frame = self.frame;
    _outerCircle.lineWidth = 4.0f;
    _outerCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.377 green:0.664 blue:0.894 alpha:1.000].CGColor;
    _outerCircle.fillColor = NULL;
    _outerCircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(self.frame, 6, 6)].CGPath;
    //_outerCircle.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    //_outerCircle.shouldRasterize = YES;
    //[self.layer addSublayer:_outerCircle];
}

@end
```

The view it's being created like this in another view (which it's in a UITableViewCell, not that I think it matters, but still...)

```
IntercomButton *intercomButton = [[IntercomButton alloc] initWithFrame:btn.frame];
intercomButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[detailView addSubview:intercomButton];
```

The UIControl view it's being added fine, because if I change the background color, it shows.

Also, If I use drawRect to draw, It works:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.377 green:0.664 blue:0.894 alpha:1.000].CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect (context, CGRectInset(rect, 12, 12));
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0f);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.377 green:0.664 blue:0.894 alpha:1.000].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectInset(rect, 8, 8));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

The problem is I need to animate it, so I need to use CAShapeLayers.
And what I'm trying to draw should look like this (this is how it looks using drawRect:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll be damned, the problem was with doing

```
CGRectInset(self.frame, X, X)
```

when I should have been doing

```
CGRectInset(self.bounds, X, X)
```

So tha layers where getting positioned outside the view frame.

As I said, it ended being something obvious.